# ¿Como seguir capturando la url después de que la pagina se ha cargado por primera vez?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos espero puedan ayudarme con este problema ya que he buscado pero no he podido encontrar la solución de antemano gracias.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación capturo la url de la pagina o formulario y guardo el resultado en una variable de tipo string esto lo hace correctamente ya que entra en el punto de interrupción, pero cuando cuando escribo otro nombre de formulario este ya no entra en el punto de interrupción por lo que ya no me guarda el nombre del formulario.

¿Alguien sabe como seguir obteniendo el nombre del formulario después de que se haya cargado por primera vez la pagina?

Este es mi código:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // La primera vez obtengo el nombre del formulario.
            string url_pagina = Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // El resultado que obtengo es: /Prueba.aspx
            lblNombre_Pagina.Text = url_pagina;
            // Despues de que la pagina cargo escribo el nombre de otro formulario por ejemplo: Prueba2.aspx pero este ya no lo obtengo por lo tanto no me redirige a google me redirige a la pagina Prueba2.aspx y ya no entra en el punto de interrupcion
            if (url_pagina != "/Prueba.aspx")
            {
                Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Podrias usar un SESSION y ahi mantener el nombre

Comment: Session["url_pagina "]=Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

Comment: pero la definicion del `Page_Load` en que pagina la defines? si es un codigo que esta en `Prueba.aspx` solo va aplicar a este, si quiere ejecute en `Prueba2.aspx` deberas definir este mismo codigo en la pagina 2

Comment: Gracias @LeandroTuttini lo he puesto en la master page para no colocar y repetir el código en cada pagina,